# How to send to send get request to api in Ember cli

Tags: ember.js, command-line-interface

```
createData: function(){
    var record = this.get('store').createRecord('ot-list');
    this.set('model', record);
 }.on('init');
```

Error while perform action on button,i want to creating record on model and i want to send post request to api.bUt it gives error
'createRecord' is not defined.what should i do...please help me out

Answer (score 1):

first of all where are u calling this method createRecord ?

if u calling this on component then store is not available on component.

this should be done in controller/route

Answer (score 0):

The store is, by default, only injected into routes and controllers. If you want to access the store in a component, you have to inject it yourself.

A good way to do so is to call `Ember.inject.service()`:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  ...
});
```

Another way is to inject it globally into all components with an initializer:

```
export function initialize(application) {
  application.inject('component', 'store', 'service:store');
};

export default {
  name: 'store-in-components',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Comment: In the first approach pls explain how to get store ?....I tried store: Ember.inject.service('store') - it worked.